# Compound Javascript Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got this page I'm doing some tests in Javascript and jQuery: [JS Tests](http://geerswitch.in/tests/obj/)

I've got a few questions on how to create, not sure if this is right term, but compound controls via Javascript.  In something like Flash, you'd create the Object class, have the getters and setters, draw your images, etc.  In JS, it seems to be a very different thought process.  My main question is **How do you create multiple elements with getters and setters to be rendered, filtered, and interacted with in Javascript?**

The main code regarding this example sits with:

```
var html = (function(){
    // var FRAG = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
    htmlBox = $(document.createElement("div"));
    var eTitle = $(document.createElement("h4"));
    var ePrice = $(document.createElement("p"));

    // set class first
    htmlBox.addClass("box")
    htmlBox.css({
        backgroundColor : color
    })

    // set text values
    eTitle.text(title);
    ePrice.text("$" + price);

    htmlBox.append(eTitle)
    htmlBox.append(ePrice)

    return htmlBox;
})();
```

... inside the Box() class.  If someone could take a look at the source and let me know what isn't quite right, that'd be great.

**EDIT**

Here's the final result for this example.  Some logistics to work out, but what I'm after.

http://geerswitch.in/tests/obj/

As for the jQuery creating nodes, the built in JS version works fine for this, and some research on Google shows that the non-jquery way is faster in most cases anyway (and looks worse, imo)

Comment: You might prefer client-side template engines for this (jQuery's is great), since it seems much more appropriate. Your document fragment is a good idea, although jQuery IIRC does that for you in compound statements anyway, so there's no need to do all the hard work - there won't be much gain and your code is much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it almost right.  You've created a `Box` class to represent your higher-order UI element, you're instantiating it for each element, and your main program is manipulating the elements through its interface.  The only thing you're missing is the split between the public interface and the private implementation.  There's nothing to prevent me from doing `myBox.price += 10` right now, even though the `Box` interface clearly implies that `price` should be set at construction and never modified.

JavaScript doesn't have visibility modifiers like "private" and "public", but you can create the same effect yourself.  Check out [Douglas Crockford's explanation](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) for the details.  Crockford is an opinionated genius when it comes to JavaScript, and he's the brains behind JSLint and JSON.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It's just a matter of getting in JS mode :)